# `GlueSchemaRegistryDeserializerDataParser` replacement in aws-sdk-java-v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-msk

We're using the `GlueSchemaRegistryDeserializerDataParser` class from https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry.
This seems to be from the v1 of the AWS SDK (or am I wrong?)

Is there a replacement in [aws-sdk-java-v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2)?